JumpList icon: how to do it correctly?
I'm using the Windows API Code Pack to create a jump list, which functions perfectly.... except for the icons.
I tried to use ICO files, defining the IconReference like this:
task.IconReference = new IconReference("MyIcon.ico", 0);

I tried to use an icon library DLL, defining the IconReference as:
task.IconReference = new IconReference("MyDll.dll", 0); // either with a 0-based index

and 

task.IconReference = new IconReference("MyDll", 101); 


But the icons never materialize.
Does anyone know
